# Postgres update jsonb string to array

Tags: arrays, postgresql, jsonb

I have a table where column2 is type JSONB and I would like to alter the values where column2 is a string to an array. I would like the result for column2 to have "one" be ["one"] and "third" be ["third"]

Table

| column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- |
| First | ["one", "two", "three"] |
| Second | "one" |
| Third | "third" |
| Third | 4 |

How should I be updating the value?
Here's what I have tried:

```
UPDATE table 
SET columnn2 = ARRAY[value]::JSONB 
WHERE jsonb_typeof(column2)!='array';
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `jsonb_build_array()` function:

```sql
update my_table set
    column2 = jsonb_build_array(column2)
where jsonb_typeof(column2) != 'array';
```

Test it in [db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=f964cdfbf00b344bc5238231e7a842db)

Read about the function [in the documentation.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html)

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use concatenation operators(**`||`**) to wrap up the expresion with square brackets along with casting to `TEXT`, then recasting to `JSONB` such as

```sql
UPDATE tab
   SET column2 = ('['||column2::TEXT||']')::JSONB
 WHERE jsonb_typeof(column2) != 'array'
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=519e580551e8de1a03990ffbb07ce3eb)</kbd>